# Http response 0 for Ajax call from Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, http

I am trying to do an AJAX call (POST) to the the php page which is in the same folder as my javascript. I am getting `http.status = 0` and `http.readyState = 4`

This is the js code:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "processor.php";
var params = "processad=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
  alert("status: " + http.status);
  alert("ready state: " + http.readyState);
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    alert(http.responseText);
  }
}
http.send(params);
```

and this is php code

```
if (isset($_POST['processad'])) {

    echo "reads";

}
```

I can figure out what is wrong here. Both files(js and php) are in the same folder, and the path for php file is relative. Not sure what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Addition:

```
HTTP request looks like this
Request URL:http://as.cbothemes.com/ads_script/processor.php
Request Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:http://as.cbothemes.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http:_/_/_as.cbothemes.com/ads_script/12.html?i=100&j=12&cb=1367948759088
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
processad:ipsum
name:binny
```

Comment: so have you actually taken a look at the http traffic? what does it look like?

Comment: When is this code called? A button being clicked? Does the button happen to also submit a form? An anchor being clicked? Does the anchor still navigate the page away?

Comment: I added http request. Code is called manually ( opening html page with JS code)

Comment: do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think that it may be permission issue

Comment: I added permission to the php file to be 777 but doesn't help. anyone have an idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because I couldn't find help here, I just transfered javascript ajax call to jQuery. So that is my solution that I don't like, but it works.